# Keycloak w/ Postgres does not start on run

Tags: postgresql, docker, jboss, keycloak

I am trying to run `Keycloak` w/ `Postgres` locally using docker.

```
$ docker network create keycloak-network
$ docker volume create pgdata
$ docker run -d -p 127.0.0.1:5432:5432 --name postgres --net keycloak-network -e POSTGRES_DB=keycloak -e POSTGRES_USER=keycloak -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password -v pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data postgres
$ docker run --name keycloak --net keycloak-network -p 8080:8080 -e KEYCLOAK_USER=admin -e KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD=admin jboss/keycloak
```

This fails when building `Keycloak`.

> 13:51:13,388 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread
>   Pool -- 61) MSC000001: Failed to start service
>   jboss.deployment.unit."keycloak-server.war".undertow-deployment:
>   org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service
>   jboss.deployment.unit."keycloak-server.war".undertow-deployment:
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: RESTEASY003325: Failed to construct public
>   org.keycloak.services.resources.KeycloakApplication(javax.servlet.ServletContext,org.jboss.resteasy.core.Dispatcher)
>     at
>   org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:81)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)     at
>   org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
>     at
>   org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1982)
>     at
>   org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
>     at
>   org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)    at
>   org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:485) Caused by:
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: RESTEASY003325: Failed to construct public
>   org.keycloak.services.resources.KeycloakApplication(javax.servlet.ServletContext,org.jboss.resteasy.core.Dispatcher)
>     at
>   org.jboss.resteasy.core.ConstructorInjectorImpl.construct(ConstructorInjectorImpl.java:164)
>     at
>   org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyProviderFactory.createProviderInstance(ResteasyProviderFactory.java:2750)
>     at
>   org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment.createApplication(ResteasyDeployment.java:364)
>     at
>   org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment.startInternal(ResteasyDeployment.java:277)
>     at
>   org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment.start(ResteasyDeployment.java:89)
>     at
>   org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.init(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:119)
>     at
>   org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.init(HttpServletDispatcher.java:36)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.core.LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.proceed(LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.java:117)
>     at
>   org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.RunAsLifecycleInterceptor.init(RunAsLifecycleInterceptor.java:78)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.core.LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.proceed(LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.java:103)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedServlet$DefaultInstanceStrategy.start(ManagedServlet.java:303)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedServlet.createServlet(ManagedServlet.java:143)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$2.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:583)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$2.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:554)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:42)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
>     at
>   org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
>     at
>   org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
>     at
>   org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
>     at
>   org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
>     at
>   org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.start(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:596)
>     at
>   org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:97)
>     at
>   org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:78)
>     ... 8 more Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to connect
>   to database   at
>   org.keycloak.connections.jpa.DefaultJpaConnectionProviderFactory.getConnection(DefaultJpaConnectionProviderFactory.java:382)
>     at
>   org.keycloak.connections.jpa.updater.liquibase.lock.LiquibaseDBLockProvider.lazyInit(LiquibaseDBLockProvider.java:65)
>     at
>   org.keycloak.connections.jpa.updater.liquibase.lock.LiquibaseDBLockProvider.lambda$waitForLock$0(LiquibaseDBLockProvider.java:97)
>     at
>   org.keycloak.models.utils.KeycloakModelUtils.suspendJtaTransaction(KeycloakModelUtils.java:678)
>     at
>   org.keycloak.connections.jpa.updater.liquibase.lock.LiquibaseDBLockProvider.waitForLock(LiquibaseDBLockProvider.java:95)
>     at
>   org.keycloak.services.resources.KeycloakApplication$1.run(KeycloakApplication.java:144)
>     at
>   org.keycloak.models.utils.KeycloakModelUtils.runJobInTransaction(KeycloakModelUtils.java:227)
>     at
>   org.keycloak.services.resources.KeycloakApplication.(KeycloakApplication.java:137)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native
>   Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>     at
>   org.jboss.resteasy.core.ConstructorInjectorImpl.construct(ConstructorInjectorImpl.java:152)
>     ... 31 more Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException:
>   datasources/KeycloakDS -- service
>   jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.datasources.KeycloakDS    at
>   org.jboss.as.naming.ServiceBasedNamingStore.lookup(ServiceBasedNamingStore.java:106)
>     at org.jboss.as.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:207)
>     at org.jboss.as.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:184)
>     at
>   org.jboss.as.naming.InitialContext$DefaultInitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:239)
>     at org.jboss.as.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:193)
>     at org.jboss.as.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:189)
>     at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417)  at
>   javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417)   at
>   org.keycloak.connections.jpa.DefaultJpaConnectionProviderFactory.getConnection(DefaultJpaConnectionProviderFactory.java:375)
>     ... 43 more

Running `Keycloak` w/ the default `h2` instance works perfectly so I can only assume this is related to hooking up `Postgres`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like keycloak cannot connect to the database

`Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to connect to database`

I find it easier to use docker-compose to start multiple services. Here is my `docker-compose.yml` for postgres & keycloak I use locally

```
version: "3"
services:
  keycloak:
    image: jboss/keycloak
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    environment:
      - KEYCLOAK_USER=admin
      - KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD=password
      - KEYCLOAK_HTTP_PORT=8484
      - TEMPLATE_MODE=true
      - DB_VENDOR=POSTGRES
      - DB_ADDR=postgres
    ports:
      - 8484:8484
      - 8485:80
      - 8486:8080
  postgres:
    image: postgres:11.2
    volumes:
      - data-volume3:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=keycloak
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
      - POSTGRES_DB=keycloak
    ports:
      - 7654:5432
volumes:
  data-volume3:
```